# what does it mean: "Lowess smooth"

Tags: meaning

what does it mean: "Lowess smooth" in following picture

[image: Graph showing "proportions of elections" on the y-axis over a span of years between pre-1800 to year 2000 on the x-axis. The curve starts low on the left, then keeps going in wave but in the end ends up a lot higher (It started at y-value about 0.5, and ended at around 3.4, with its highest point at 5.3 and lowest point at around 0.1]

Comment: Please provide more context; as it is now, it is difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I would advise a book on statistics. Like your other question, this  has little to do with English, and everything with statistics. I can almost feel questions coming up about the difference between mean and average, or about quartile definitions.

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search for 'Lowess' reveals it's a technical term:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression